# How to pass text to listview android tabbed activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have fragment 1 content edittext and fragment 2 content listview ,how to pass data from 1 to 2.
note : not textview Iwant to listview.

Comment: Please add some code of what you've tried, errors or any other informations

Comment: Ambiguous Question
is your listview custom ? 
should your listview show only a text ?

Comment: Hello friend You seem to have experience in Android programming, I have a problem and I want you to solve this problem. I have already posted my problem in stackoverflow but I can not find the right solution. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
Fragment A{

      ArrayList<Model> mList;
      Adapter... mAdapter;
      String str =null;

      public ArrayList<Model> getList(){return mList;}
      public void setList(ArrayList<Model> l){this.mList = l;}

      public void setStr(String s){
           this.str = s;
           //handle here
      }

      }

Fragment B{
       TextView mTextView;
       Fragment A a;
       ArrayList<Model> mList;

       //you can change content of a list here
       mList = a.getList();
       mList...
       //Or 
       a.setStr(myTextView.getText().toString());
       }
```

Comment: Hello friend You seem to have experience in Android programming, I have a problem and I want you to solve this problem. I have already posted my problem in stackoverflow but I can not find the right solution. Can you help me?